# Separate linux terminal input based on new line using Java

Tags: java, linux, split, newline, user-input

I'm trying to separate the terminal input into a Java code based on new lines.

Here is the current code I have.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String initial_input = sc.nextLine();

String[] lines = initial_input.split("\\r?\\n");

for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Here is my input:

```
INSERT KEY adam key\nTURN KEY adam\nENTER HOUSE adam\nINSERT KEY pat foobar\nTURN KEY pat\nENTER HOUSE pat\nWHO'S INSIDE?
```

It doesn't print lines separately.. instead it print all in one line.

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As `split` takes a regular expression argument carriage return characters need to be escaped to match characters literally

```
String[] lines = initial_input.split("(\\\\r)?\\\\n");
```

Comment: Unless I've missed something, `sc.nextLine()` *should* only read one line.

Answer (score 0):

It should be with  `\\\\n`

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String initial_input = sc.nextLine();

String[] lines = initial_input.split("\\\\n");

for (String line : lines) {
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some misconceptions about regular expressions and text.

As Reimeus said before, you have to escape the pattern once more with two backslashes (`\\\\n`). That's because what you're typing on the keyboard is just one line of text.

Right here

```
INSERT KEY adam key\nTURN KEY adam\nENTER HOUSE adam\nINSERT KEY pat foobar\nTURN KEY pat\nENTER HOUSE pat\nWHO'S INSIDE?
```

This input is just one line. Those `\n` are not `newline` characters. They are just two separate characters. One of them containing the `backslash` character (code 0x5C) and the other containing the `n` character (code 0x6E).

The actual `newline` character is just one single character (code 0x0A), represented as `\n` in source code because the real character is not visible (it's just a mark of a new line).

On the other hand, `Scanner.nextLine()` reads just one line, until it finds the `newline` character, that you entered when pressed the `ENTER` key on the keyboard.

Your code does actually split a text into several lines, but your input is just one line long.

You can either read from a file with several lines in it, or split one line in some strings, taking the `backslash` and `n` character as separators.